# Computation of balance equation example in Markov model

Tags: markov-process, transition-matrix

I am studying some examples of *[balance equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_equation)* for Markov models. I am presented with the following example:

> $$\mathcal{P} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.5 \\ 0.1 & 0 & 0.9 \\ 0.55 & 0 & 0.45 \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> [dropping the $i$ subscript by writing $\pi_j$ for $\pi_{ij}.]$
>
> The balance equations are
>
> $$\begin{align} &\pi_1 = 0.2 \pi_1 + 0.1 \pi_2 + 0.55 \pi_3 \tag{a} \\ &\pi_2 = 0.3 \pi_1 \tag{b} \\ &\pi_3 = 0.5 \pi_1 + 0.9 \pi_2 + 0.45 \pi_3 \tag{c} \end{align}$$
>
> Since, also, $\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1$, the unique solution is
>
> $$\pi_1 = \frac1{2.7} = 0.37037, \ \ \ \pi_2 = \frac19 = 0.11111, \ \ \ \pi_3 = \frac{1.4}{2.7} = 0.51852$$

How do we solve this for the values $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$? Is there a way to solve this using matrix computations? The difficulty here, as I see it, is that we have a constraint $\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1$ that must hold, so I'm unsure of how this is done.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve linear system of equations.

Equation $(a)$ can be converted to $$(0.2-1)\pi_1 + 0.1\pi_2 + 0.55\pi_3=0\tag{a'}$$

Similarly for $b$ and $c$.

Also, with the constraint $\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3=1$

We have $3$ variables and $4$ constraints.

$$\pi=P^T\pi$$
$$e^T\pi=1$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} P^T-I \\ e^T\end{bmatrix}\pi =\begin{bmatrix} 0_3 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

You can perform Gaussian Elimination to get the solution.

Here is the Octave solution:

```
octave:1> A = [-0.8, 0.1, 0.55, 0; 0.3, -1, 0, 0; 0.5,  0.9, -0.55,  0; 1, 1, 1, 1]
A =

  -0.80000   0.10000   0.55000   0.00000
   0.30000  -1.00000   0.00000   0.00000
   0.50000   0.90000  -0.55000   0.00000
   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000

octave:2> rref(A)
ans =

   1.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.37037
   0.00000   1.00000   0.00000   0.11111
   0.00000   0.00000   1.00000   0.51852
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Comment: I'm confused about where these came from: $$\pi=P^T\pi,$$ $$e^T\pi=1,$$ $$\begin{bmatrix} P^T-I \\ e^T\end{bmatrix}\pi =\begin{bmatrix} 0_3 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$ And what is $e^T$ supposed to be? Is it the transpose of the constant $e$? What does it mean to have the transpose of a constant, and where did it come from?

Comment: oops, it's my habit to use $e$ to denote the column vector of length $n$. It comes from $\pi_i$'s sums up to $1$. $\pi^T=\pi^TP$ are the balance equations.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Where did $\begin{bmatrix} P^T-I \\ e^T\end{bmatrix}\pi =\begin{bmatrix} 0_3 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ come from?

Comment: From $\pi^T=\pi^TP$, take transpose, you get $P^T\pi = \pi$, move the right hand side to left hand side and you will get $(P^T-I)\pi = 0$, now append it with $e^T\pi=1$.

Comment: Ahh, yes, of course. Very interesting. Thank you for taking the time to clarify!